# Accessing properties and object from an jQuery click event create in the same object

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have an jscript object. I insert some html in a div, and i try to attach an event click to 
an html label, all insede the object, by how can access methods and properties of object inside
jquery click event function?

HTML code:

```
<div id="content"></div>
```

JAVASCRIPT code:

```
<SCRIPT ...
jQuery().ready(function (){
    obj=new myobject("myobject1","#content"); //create object instance
    obj.dohtml(); //call method dohtml
});

//object I pass an objectname and a id from an html element 
function myobject(objectname,htmlid){

    this.name=objectname; //name of object 
    this.htmlid=htmlid;   //id where i try to create some html

    //say hello
    this.hello=function(){
       alert(hello); 
    }

    //do something with html
    this.dohtml=function(){

    //create an <p> element in a the html with id=htmlid 
    $(this.htmlid).html('<p id="'+this.name+'_myp" > my text </p>')     

    //click event on <p> id= this.name+'_myp"
    $("#"+this.name+'_myp').click(function(){
        alert(this.name); //i try to access property this.name in the object and dont work
        //how can access to this property from here

        this.hello(); //how can access to this method from here

    });

    $("#"+this.name+'_myp').click(this.hello()); //this dont work too why?

 } 

}
```

Answer (score 2):

your scope changes inside the `click` callback.. so you need to keep the `this` var stored:

```
var that = this;
$("#"+this.name+'_myp').click(function(){
    alert(that.name); //i try to access property this.name in the object and dont work
    that.hello(); //how can access to this method from here
});
```

#### For the second part:

you're executing the function and passing the return value when you do `this.hello()`, if you just want to pass the function, you would pass `this.hello` with no `()`

```
$("#"+this.name+'_myp').click(this.hello);
```

it works with `this` because you are still in scope.

Comment: you are right, sorry I a new with javascript. ¿is this the correct from to encapsulate my work?